# Can't figure out why my nav bar is shoved to the right

Tags: css, position

Here it is in jsbin. But I can upload the files also if needed. Everything is out of place due to the missing images and other files. But my only problem is the right side of the nav bar. "About us, Blog, Saftey, Help, Download Now" are all being push to the edge of the screen while the Logoicon and "Outbank" are staying within the center container as they should.

The navbar links on the right should be exactly like the 2 on the left, just on the right side instead of left.

I am learning html and CSS so I am just looking up sites and trying to remake them from scratch. It's the only way I can think of to get better at since I have no one to teach me. All the Udemy courses and only text-courses are missing something for my brain. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

You will probably have to drag the HTML/CSS panels all the way to the left of the page to see what I am refering too. The navbar should be just like on this stack overflow page. The StackIcon, "stackoverflow" then links to the right. All staying center of the page with the width of the container. 
http://jsbin.com/nodifoxama/edit?html,css,output

Comment: where is your html codes?

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    //add
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason that switched it around. Now the Brandname and icon are against the left, and the right side is working lol. It looks good this way so I am ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your grid design is not working correctly because your CSS is not handling when the  browser screen is reduced in size.

If you are new to CSS and HTML, I would strongly suggest implementing CSS Bootstrap in your web page rather than writing a custom CSS responsive page.  You can start by following W3Schools tutorial on Bootstrap in order to better understand responsive design:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Yeah I am pretty new, that's why I am trying to avoid using bootstrap. I already learned it well, but I want to be able to do it manually also rather than just utilizing the framework.